# Inspector is disabled in unity

Tags: unity-game-engine

I added a blender file to my assets, and when I click on this file in assets I can't add a component such as `SkinnedMeshRenderer` to the imported asset as shown in this [screenshot](https://www.dropbox.com/s/p7voktgtktlk0sq/disabled.JPG?dl=0). How I can add it?

Comment: Is Blender installed?

Comment: @MickyDuncan yes it is. The problem is in unity not blender right?

Comment: Just checking.  I had problems importing Blender-created assets a while back.  I forgot to re-install Blender after formatting the computer.

Comment: @MickyDuncan I can import it, but the inspector is disabled

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `SkinnedMeshRenderer` is not something you can just add in Unity.
As said in the documentation:

> Unity uses the Skinned Mesh Renderer component to render Bone animations, where the shape of the mesh is deformed by predefined animation sequences.

A `SkinnedMeshRenderer` is automatically added when a skeleton is found in your asset. To have a `SkinnedMeshRenderer` you must export a skeleton from blender. If you don't have a skeleton, it means that a `SkinnedMeshRenderer` is not required.

Answer (score 0):

The "Imported Object" is a Unity asset that doesn't accept additional components.  Try creating a prefab (right click in Project folder and select Create -> Prefab), give it a unique name, and then drag the "Imported Object" mentioned above, from the Project panel not from the inspector, onto the newly created prefab object in the Project panel.  Components can now be added to the prefab.  Whenever referencing blender models access them through prefabs in such a way.  Prefab copies can be added to the scene by clicking and dragging the prefab into the scene or by using GameObject.Instantiate with scripts.